# How to identify sender when they send monero?

Tags: sub-address, transaction-key

My current understanding is that when I expect to receive monero from many people, I send each subaddress to each one of them to identify which one sent how much. But it seems to be troublesome for me to generate a lot of subaddresses.
So I will just have an address and people send monero to that. Then they send me an email with 2 information TXID TXKEY so I can check it.
Is that the correct way ?

Comment: Sidenote: this question title is the biggest clickbait title I have seen

Answer (score 4):

You could do that, if you want something way more cumbersome than giving a different address to everyone. Another, more secure way is to get the sender to generate a proof of sending a transaction (see `get_tx_proof` and `check_tx_proof`), but that is also more cumbersome than using a subaddress per sender.